# Options for nonparametric preference ranking models

Tags: logistic, nonparametric, ranking, nonlinear

What are some options for nonparametric ranking models with a probabilistic interpretation?

I'm basically looking for a nonlinear/nonparametric version of a rank ordered logit model.

I'm aware of some literature in the "learning to rank" space for information retrieval, but I'm looking for something with more continuous scores (item X is twice as likely to be chosen compared to item Y) rather than just a simple rank ordered list.